# how to swipe Mail in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app

I don't remember if I was using android or the gmail app, but I was able to swipe to move to the next or previous mail (in any of the mail apps).

I am now using an iPhone, so how can I achieve this? is it configurable? another mail app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's native mail app doesn't allow swipe to work that way on iPhone since swipes are for marking / archiving / moving or deleting by design.

On larger iOS devices - portrait mode works the same as the iPhone (non S size) but landscape mode has a navigation sidebar for navigating.

It's not a swipe, but it helps triage mails for me.

You might look at [Inbox by Gmail](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/inbox-by-gmail/id905060486?mt=8) on iOS - it has a snooze feature that could be used to swipe past mails like tinder allows you to swipe to filter and file a queue of people.